# socket.io is not working and my flutter app is not being connected to server or backend part

Tags: android, node.js, json, flutter, socket.io

I used `socket.io` and `node.js` for my backend part in my flutter app. I made a file `index.json` and made a function in a page to connect my app to backend. But it doesn't work. Here is the function, which i called in `initstate` -

```
void connect() {
    socket = IO.io("http://my ip address", <String, dynamic>{
      "transports":["websocket"],
      "autoConnect":false,
    });
    socket.connect();
    socket.onConnect((data) => print("Connected"));
    print(socket.connected);
    socket.emit("/test", "Hello World");
  }
  


    @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    connect();
    //Some other code
  }
```

Here is `index.js` file -

```
const express = require("express");
var http = require("http");
 const cors = require("cors");
 const app = express();
 const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;
 var server = http.createServer(app);
 var io = require("socket.io")(server, {
     cors:
     {
        origin:"*"
     }
 });

 //middlewre
 app.use(express.json());
 app.use(cors());

 io.on("connection", (socket)=>{
    console.log("connected");
    console.log(socket.id, " has joined");
    socket.on("/test", (msg)=>{
       console.log(msg);
    });
 });

 server.listen(port,"0.0.0.0",()=> {
    console.log("server started");
 })
```

In run log, it is showing/printing false only

Comment: Are you testing on your local server with an Android emulator?

Comment: @JoãoSoares yes

Comment: did you find a way to do it ?

Answer (score 5):

As it seems you are testing with an Android emulator, you can't use `127.0.0.1` to connect to your localhost, you need to use the address `10.0.2.2`.

You will also need to use the `ws://` protocol instead of `http://`.

You can find the official documentation here: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking

Comment: Can you please elaborate how can i achieve this? I have a very little idea about backend part. If you wantm i can edit this post and add more info, if that can help. Or please tell me about the file on which i should go through the changes to achieve what you are saying. I am reading the documentation, but if you can help me out here, it would be great.

Comment: You are running the socket.io server on your local machine, correct? Instead of setting localhost or 127.0.0.1 on `IO.io("http://my ip address"`, use the IP above `10.0.2.2`.

Comment: I've added an extra bit of information regarding the protocol to my answer.